# Custom terminate script in IntelliJ IDEA to stop jsvc

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jsvc

I'm trying to debug my Java application which should run as a daemon and therefore gets launched by [jsvc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html). At the moment I'm launching it with the help of Gradle as a IDEA Run/Debug configuration.

The problem is that IDEA (when clicking on the "Terminate" button) tries to kill the Gradle build and then (after like ten seconds) fails with the error message

```
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip'.
```

Am I somehow able to provide a custom terminate script to IDEA?

Comment: Custom scripts are supported only for certain web application server run/debug configurations in IntelliJ IDEA.